# How to make a turn server on node.js for peer connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, turn, peer-connection

I'm using a node.js server to send iceCandidates and connect two computers by peer connection (javascript). I want to use TURN-server as iceServer, but I don't have one, so I want to make TURN-server on my server. How is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want to use TURN-server as iceServer", but if I understand correctly you want to implement your own TURN-server. Just install [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) and configure your clients to use it. This will be a lot easier than to implement your own solution.

Comment: @Mikko, that should maybe be an answer...

Comment: @catbadger thanks for the note. Yeah I guess, it doesn't really answer the question of writing your own server, but it is the correct thing to do

Answer (score 8):

you can use [node-turn](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/node-turn) to write your own server or using it as a standalone server.

```
var Turn = require('node-turn');
var server = new Turn({
  // set options
  authMech: 'long-term',
  credentials: {
    username: "password"
  }
});
server.start();
```

Comment: Can we use it along with express server?